# php for loop code not executing subsequent values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code and unable to get expected result

```
function addempreport($empBCTID, $Year, $SMonth, $Emonth){
    echo $empBCTID."\n";
    $arr = explode(',', $empBCTID );
    print_r($arr)."\n";
    echo count($arr)."\n";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        echo $arr[$i]."\n";
        echo $i."\n";
        $AttString = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        $x = $SMonth;
        $bctid = $arr[$i];
            echo $bctid."\n";
        for ($x = $SMonth; $x <= $Emonth; $x++) {
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO empreporttest (empBCTID, Year, Month, AttString) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("siis", $bctid, $Year, $x, $AttString);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo $SMonth."Continue".$bctid.$Year.$x.$Emonth."\n";
        }
        echo $i."\n";
    }
    if($stmt->execute()) return true;
    
    return false;
    
}
```

The Postman captured the messages and is as follows:

```
BCT-303, BCT-302
Array
(
[0] => BCT-303
[1] => BCT-302
)
2
BCT-303
0
BCT-303
6ContinueBCT-3032023612
6ContinueBCT-3032023712
6ContinueBCT-3032023812
6ContinueBCT-3032023912
6ContinueBCT-30320231012
6ContinueBCT-30320231112
6ContinueBCT-30320231212
0
BCT-302
1
BCT-302
6Continue BCT-3022023612
6Continue BCT-3022023712
6Continue BCT-3022023812
6Continue BCT-3022023912
6Continue BCT-30220231012
6Continue BCT-30220231112
6Continue BCT-30220231212
1
{"message":"Employee Added"}
```

Inputs given are:

```
empBCTID:BCT-303, BCT-302
Year:2023
SMonth:6
Emonth:12
```

The first ID - 303 has added the data, but the second one 302 is not getting executed in the MySQL data table. There are no php errors.

Answer (score 0):

My input data is wrong.

```
empBCTID:BCT-303, BCT-302
```

It should be:

```
empBCTID:BCT-303,BCT-302
```

as there is no space eater!!